# Quantum Communication - Tx/Rx terminolgy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, quantum-entanglement

When talking about Quantum Communication vs. Classical Communication data is passed via quantum entanglement; data doesn't traverse the space between the involved particles.  Is one particle "transmitting" and one particle "receiving" or is there alternative terminology used in quantum mechanics that describes this action more accurately?

Answer (score 2):

There is no *causal* relationship between the two qubits whatsoever. The results are simply *correlated*: by making measurements on one qubit you can make conclusions about various measurements that could be made on the other qubit. Critically, there's nothing you can do to your qubit that someone with the other qubit can detect: its only with later comparison that they can tell their measurement had any correlation with yours at all.

If you want to actually communicate, a classical channel needs to be involved.

Answer (score 0):

Entanglement between quantum identities are like wires in classical setting, it doesn't transmit information by itself. To send/receive information actual qubit need to be passed along or measurement results needs to be sent via classical channel.